# How to set focus to a specific TextField object?

Tags: codenameone

I am looking for a method to set the focus on a specific `Component`, in this case a `TextField`, when the `Form` in question gains the primary focus. I iterated over the available methods of `Component` and all its subclasses and have not found any. Of course I may have skipped something by mistake.

Comment: Do you mean you want to focus the cursor on the specific TextField? If yes, check the `startEditingAsync();` method

Comment: @fnklstn Thank you for pointing out the method.

Comment: @fnklstn is correct. There's `requestFocus()` but you probably want editing. Also if the form isn't showing yet and you want it to launch while editing a specific field use `Form.setEditOnShow(field)`.

Comment: Thanks @ShaiAlmog. I do not know yet if I am going to need this feature.